# Can't append multiple times with self-defined oracle

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, cirq

```
import cirq


def set_io_qubits(qubit_count):
    input_qubits = [cirq.GridQubit(i, 0) for i in range(qubit_count)]
    return (input_qubits)

def debug_oracle(input_qubits):
    yield (cirq.H(input_qubits[0]))


def make_grover_circuit(input_qubits, oracle):
    c = cirq.Circuit()

    c.append(oracle)
    c.append(oracle)
    c.append(oracle)

    c.append(cirq.measure(*input_qubits, key='result'))

    return c


def main():
    input_qubits = set_io_qubits(2)

    oracle = debug_oracle(input_qubits)

    circuit = make_grover_circuit(input_qubits, oracle)
    print('Circuit:')
    print(circuit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I add `c.append(oracle)` three times in `make_grover_circuit`. However, when I print the circuit, it seems there is only one `oracle`. Is it a bug? Or just I can't `.append` my oracle more than once? Here is my result of the program.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /Users/a123/Desktop/Cirq/test.py
Circuit:
(0, 0): ───H───M('result')───
               │
(1, 0): ───────M─────────────

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using the result of a generator method multiple times:

```
def gen():
    yield 1
g = gen()
print(list(g))  # prints [1]
print(list(g))  # prints []
```

This is a common mistake to make in Python. The solution is to store a list of the items instead of the generator:

```
def gen():
    yield 1

gen_items_safe_to_reuse = list(gen())
```